# Merge/alias [stub] and [stubs]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

There seems to be no reason to keep both of them separate: [stub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stub) vs [stubs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stubs)

Comment: I think both tags are stubs...